# Why does Kip Irvine's readChar not echo user input, while readInt does?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I have a question regarding Kip Irvine's include32 file.

So he has this call called readChar and readInt which I'm pretty sure many of you have used and although they have very similar description to what they do, they act differently.

For instance, consider the following partial code (I just came up with it on the fly sorry if there are any errors)

```
Title    Sample     (Sample.asm)

include Irvine32.inc

.data
query   byte   "Enter something", 0
a       byte   ?
b       byte   ?

.code

main proc

mov edx, offset query
call writeString
call readChar
mov a, al

mov edx, offset query
call writeString
call readInt
mov b, eax
```

Where I use readInt allows the user inputting an int to enter the number and then have to press enter and it shows what you entered.

As where when I use readChar the user just presses the character he wants and then it gets stored into al without confirmation (without having to press enter) and it doesn't show what you entered

I know that because a char can only be a single well char therefore you don't need confirmation.
And a decimal can be more than one digit so it needs confirmation.

But why doesn't it show what you enter for readChar?

I've tried reading the irvine32.inc file but it isn't very detailed, I've also tried looking for it online and couldn't find the entire code just how it works (what registers it goes to etc). So if anybody can explain to me I'd really appreciate it or present to me an alternative way of letting the user see what he enters (without having to print out again what he entered.)

Comment: you can call `writeChar` after `readChar` to print it manually. One reason is that the default behaviour allows for fancier input. Not displaying passwords as they are typed (print an asterisk or nothing for example)

Answer (score 1):

The author has a WriteChar procedure within Irvine32.inc that is intended to call following the ReadChar procedure. An example can be found in chapter 6.6 of the text, Assembly Language for x86 Processors 7e, pg 223. ReadChar reads a single char from the keyboard, and returns the character in the AL register. WriteChar receives a char value in the AL register to write to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Because a readchar has a fixed size, and readint (in decimal) might consist out of multiple chars?  The system/runtime doesn't know if "1" is followed by another "1" to make "11" or not, so it needs an enter.

This has been the way since days of yore.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but that is not my question. My question is why does it not show what the user enters @marco

Comment: Ah, ok I missed that. You mean why it doesn't echo. I looked at the header, and it has the usual pattern for DOS libraries. I would expect readchar to echo and readkey not, I assume you did the same. So that leaves bug or documented but counterintuitive feature.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't know the proper term for it. Idk but that really bothers me, not having an echo. I guess I'll just make my own proc for reading chars then. Thanks. @marco